# Replace single occurrence of a string value in numeric variable - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a numeric variable (stored as object) where one single value is "NA", how could I replace this with a zero? Thanks!

```
df['Var_A'].loc[28:35]

28     2.99
29     7.81
30     "NA"
31    13.55
32     8.25
33      6.2
34     8.77
35     2.67
Name: Var_A, dtype: object
```

Comment: `df['Var_A'].replace("NA", 0)`

Comment: Use `df['Var_A'].replace("NA", 0).astype(float)` or `pd.to_numeric(df['Var_A'], errors='coerce')`

Comment: thanks guys, I tried both but the "NA" is still there

Comment: you missed the assignment part. Use like this. df['Var_A'] = df['Var_A'].replace("NA", 0)